# Slow SQL query, how to improve?

Tags: java, html, sql, jsp, jstl

This query works perfectly, I think. Other than it is so slow. What am I doing wrong? How can I improve the speed as well at the code in general?

```
<sql:query var="UserQuery" dataSource="jdbc/UBWT">
SELECT top 100 
dbo.v_r_system.Name0                                        as PC,
dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.User_ID                     as UBOCUBID,
dbo.v_r_user.User_Name0                                     as UBID,
dbo.v_r_user.ResourceID                                     as ResID,
dbo.v_r_user.displayName0                                   as FoolName,
dbo.v_r_user.givenName0                                     as FirstName,          
dbo.v_r_user.sn0                                            as LastName,
dbo.v_r_user.mail0                                          as eMail,
dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.Recent_Login_TimeStamp      as InFor,
dbo.v_r_user.departmentNumber0                              as DeptNum,
dbo.v_r_user.department0                                    as Dept,
dbo.v_r_user.telephoneNumber0                               as Phone
FROM        
dbo.v_r_system
inner join dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred on dbo.v_r_system.name0 = dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.computer_name
inner join dbo.v_r_user on dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.user_id = dbo.v_r_user.unique_user_name0
where dbo.v_r_system.Name0 = ? <sql:param value="${param.ubid}" />
or dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.User_ID = ? <sql:param value="${param.ubid}" />
or dbo.v_r_user.User_Name0 = ? <sql:param value="${param.ubid}" />
or dbo.v_r_user.displayName0 = ? <sql:param value="${param.ubid}" />
or dbo.v_r_user.telephoneNumber0 = ? <sql:param value="${param.ubid}" />
order by dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.Recent_Login_TimeStamp desc;
```

I really dont like all the `OR` statements. Do I need to convert to some sort of ***prepared*** statement?

Answer (score 3):

Use EXPLAIN PLAN to see why your query is slow.  If you see TABLE SCAN, eliminate them.  Or make the size of the set you scan smaller by rearranging your WHERE clauses.

Indexes might make a difference.  You should have one for every column that appears in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, nothing wrong with your query and nothing wrong with 'or' either. Speak with the database owners to investigate which columns and combination of columns in the database are *indexed*. The query optimiser may be resorting to a trundle through the database tables.

Rather insipid answer I know but not much more to say.

Answer (score 0):

If the query returns a large number of results without limiting it to 100, that could be the issue you are having.

Due to the fact that you have an `ORDER BY` statement means that if you return 10,000,000 rows with your query, it will order all of them before taking the top 100 and returning them to you, however if you leave that out, it will just return the first 100 results it comes across.

The only way I can think of getting round that is to get a proper index on the table, or return all the results where `Recent_Login_Timestamp` is within a reasonable range (i.e. one day if there are many entries).

Answer (score 0):

Generally I noted that **JSTL SQL taglib is much slower** than Java code, because it put all the result set into an `HashMap`. I think it should be used just for prototyping.

Anyway you could try to simplify your where-clause in following way and see if it helps:

```
where ? <sql:param value="${param.ubid}" /> in (
    dbo.v_r_system.Name0,
    dbo.v_computer_owners_preferred.User_ID,
    dbo.v_r_user.User_Name0,
    dbo.v_r_user.displayName0,
    dbo.v_r_user.telephoneNumber0
    )
```